# Store ASP.NET MVC3 application session on a mysql database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I've tried to store session on mysql database, but what happened, mysql server crashes because filesystem was overloaded.

I have few questions about it:

- Is a good practice store session on a database?
- When we have to take that choice?
- I have millions of updates on that database, Why ?? There's a way to controle it?? How?

That's my code on my web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" mode="Custom" timeout="24" customProvider="MySqlSessionStateProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider"
           type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
           description="MySQL Session State" connectionStringName="MySqlServerSession" 
           writeExceptionsToEventLog="False" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```